# Implementing Delegate Methods in Swift from interface

Tags: ios, swift, interface, delegates

I am trying to implement delegate methods in the source code so it can listen to changes that is exposed by a library.

I could implement this:

```
- (void)controllerDidCancel:(ControllerType *_Nonnull)module;
```

Into this: (and it gets triggered when the action is performed)

```
@objc public func controllerDidCancel(_ controller: ControllerType) {
        // some code
    }
```

But I just simply don't understand how should I implement something like the following:

```
- (void)controller:(ControllerType *_Nonnull)moudle1 controllerDidFinish:(ResponseType *_Nullable)module2;
```

Tried to simply call the second interface like so:

```
@objc public func controllerDidFinish(_ response: ResponseType) {
            // some code
}
```

With no luck... it never gets triggered.
They both are under the same delegate protocol.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The autocompletion doesn't helpyou? It should be something like `func controller(_ moudle1: ControllerType, controllerDidFinish module2: ResultType?)`

Comment: Thanks... I feel like I am an idiot. It did suggest the right implementation. Im new to XCode & Android Studio... VSCode is not so helpful... at least type hint is not needed there too much for my work.